# Power efficiency on PIC/AVR

Tags: arduino, pic, power, avr

I usually make Arduino protos without worrying about power- there will always be power so why worry. Recently I was asked to make simple device that counts clicks/ticks( a knob turning that makes a click) and logs its somewhere. Easy enough-but the problem is it needs to run concealed inside a device for 3-5 years of a battery(easily serviceable -but prefer not to)
I came  across this
http://interface.khm.de/index.php/lab/experiments/sleep_watchdog_battery/
and the theory is that it can run up to 3 years. Its fantastic because it is nearly what I want.

Has anybody every actually run a device like this for 3-5 years of a battery? In research i came to the conclusion that using Lithium Polymer would be the best battery for long term power- am I correct? and using a single 700mAh LiPo could technically last to 5 years. Is this lifetime of a battery even feasible?

Now I will try and change that project to wake the Arduino every time i get an external tick/click and it will increment,is it possible to wake the Arduino with an external event?

The second part is- Is it possible to store simple small integers inside the Arduino non-volatile memory somehow to avoid keeping it in RAM and using power?or the simplest way to store data on non-volatile memory.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily  last that long with a few coin cells in parallel. The Arduino can do sleep mode and wake up on a external pin transition, but you'll have to include debounce logic or hardware. You can also do without regulated power...

All that being said, if your primary goal is to maximize the life of your project, the ATMega328 is not your best choice. There are a variety of low-end microontrollers that are better suited to battery powered operation including (but not limited to I'm sure):

- Texas Instruments' MSP430 series
- Microchip's XLP series (as you've noted)
- Atmel's XMega microcontrollers (e.g. picoPower)

I don't want to start a flame war, but I think MSP430 is widely acknowledged as the leader in the low power market, as the whole chip was (purportedly) conceived from the ground up with low power in mind.

Comment: Fantastic- I know i need to get rid of the regulator- but I found LP2950 which has a on/off logic and designed for battery environments-but might add unnecessary elements and cost.. If i do ditch the regulator all together- can these MicroControllers handle variable voltage that will occur once the battery starts to drain.

Comment: The data sheet will have the minimum voltage.

Comment: Thanks I took a look in the MSP and XMega- and the statement on MSP Page "MSP lasts 20 years on1 battery.." umm OK that's what I want :) and 6years on 1% active.. using a single coin cell! get out of here!  Thanks man!

Comment: @ppumkin: People think that the MSP 430 are exceptionally low power for some reason. This may be because they were ahead of the pack when they first came out over 10 years ago. Nowadays the low power PICs are just as good in that regard.  Compare some datasheets.

Comment: msp430 and XLP PIC are neck-and-neck regarding power (it will depend on the application which is lower power) but the msp430 has a much nicer architecture to program against.

Comment: If you're looking for low power, don't forget to look at Epson micros as well.

Comment: end of day all the newer chips have power consumption at 1mhz in the uA ranges and working in mA with non useful things disabled. Now its just down to price per unit in bulk... Thanks for great answers. NOt sure about the Epson micros could not find anything

Comment: Some of the PIC microcontrollers are good on power consumption too now - take a look at their "NanoWatt" range

Comment: The smaller, simpler micros tend to have lower leakage currents.  So look at the low-end parts in the range.

Comment: @ppumkin, in this application you should arrange the firmware to be in sleep mode nearly 100% of the time.  So the 1MHz numbers are not as important as the sleep numbers.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PO1ICrXMIOc - @vicatcu i see what oyu mean by starting a war- each page i visited for the mentioned controllers.. well- they are all the worlds most energy efficient microcontrollers.. heheh. Even the Arduino forum tries to show methods to get the megas in to nA sleep.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need low power, then ditch the arduino and use a microcontroller directly.  With proper hardware and firmware design and the right micro, you can get average current draw into the low µA or even pA range, depending on how often the device wakes up and how long it runs when it does.  I had a project that ran for a whole year on one CR2032 coin cell, and that woke up every 10 seconds and transmitted a RF message and a IR signature.

Check out any of the "nanowatt" (pretentious marketing term, but low power nonetheless) or "XLP" PICs.  Most of these come with the newer low power watchdog that can wake the micro periodically.  It sounds like in your case you'd be waking on a external event, so your current consumption should be down to battery self-discharge levels when nothing is going on.

You don't need non-volatile storage as long as power is continuously supplied.  These parts all have CMOS static RAM, so take essentially no power just to keep the memory alive.

Comment: Brilliant - so using a LSD-NiMH instead of LiPo battery would last about 3-5 years.When you say ditch the Arduino what do you mean? As in just use the IC on its own?like in the link- i know the voltage regulator and Serial Port drain allot of power. Is it easy to programme XLP pics using an Arduino as an ISP?

Comment: @ppumkin: Arduinos are for rapid prototyping or and "microcontrollers for dummies".  For serious engineering you need to get past that and build up a system yourself.  No, PICs are not programmed from Arduinos.  That is done with a PIC programmer like the ICD3, RealIce, and others.

Comment: given the amount of Arduino projects out there, I'm sure somebody has hacked up a PIC programmer from one. (I'm not saying it's a great idea)

Comment: chipKit's are PICs that are compatible with Arduino code. You can program them with a PicKit3 as well. Kinda neat. [http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Catalog.cfm?NavPath=2,892&Cat=18](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Catalog.cfm?NavPath=2,892&Cat=18)

Comment: Don't confuse the PIC families. ChipKit is a PIC32 based kit, and the PIC32s are MIPS processors - pretty much all they have in common with PICs is the manufacturer, and they're certainly not the low power models.